# How to configure Jest in HTML file for integration tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, jasmine

I want to use integration tests that will use an external API. The external library is loaded on the fly by implementing it's URL (like google ads). So, I need to start the tests from the stage, I think. How can I configure them properly? For example, there is a Jasmine integration HTML part that I found

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
```

But what should I add for Jest testing without mocks?

UPD: Ok, can I run Jest test framework without command line? In browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Jest chat:

> Jest is not an end to end testing framework, it cannot run in a
>   browser. I think your best options are Cypress which is an end to end
>   framework that runs in Chrome, or Puppetteer if you just want to
>   manually control a browser in Jest tests.
>
> If I understand you correctly
>   you want to run on a staging/production environment directly?
>   Definitely Cypress in that case